# WebPage loads twice below in Swift IOS App Using WkWebView

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I'm developing a swift ios app which is basically a webview of an webpage. Apart from this, it has a navigationitem as its topitem. It works according to the functionality but whenever I load the page the page comes twice one below the other.

Is it due to JavaScript of the webpage not loading correctly or cache not sure?

[image: Simulator]

[image: Mobile device Browser]

The website opens just fine on any mobile device browser.

```
// Custom method 
let url = URL(string : url)
let req = URLRequest(url: url)
> webView.load(req1)
```

```
ovverride func loadView(){
webView = WkWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webconfig)
webView.uiDelegate = self
webView.navigationDelegate = self
view = webView
}
```

```
ovverride func viewDidLoad() {
// code for navigationitem
}
```

Comment: You will need to provide a [Minimal & Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if you'd like help on this.